# Get element with specific class

Tags: jquery, class, jquery-selectors

I have several divs in my variable `offers` and I want to retrieve the one with class `special`. How can I find that element? Or apply selector on variable `offers`?

For Example offers contain:

```
<div class="special">A</div>
<div class="notspecial">B</div>
<div class="notspecial">C</div>
<div class="special">D</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.filter()` function to filter out elements based on condition in returned set:

```
var splofferelements = offers.filter('.special')
```

Comment: One more question, I have to apply siblings method on my offers object. How can I do that?

`$().siblings("div.notspecialoffer:lt(3)");`

Comment: @HumaAli: didn't get you. can you elaborate more or post new question?